# I want to make this VBA code non case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
    'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Wrap everything in `LCASE` or `UCASE` before you compare?

Comment: Can you also include where/why you want to implement this? It may just be possible in a build-in function.

Comment: As @Jvdv said.  At the moment it looks like a `VLOOKUP`/`XLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Two more ways besides the provided answer.

**WAY 1**

Type `Option Compare Text` at the very top. For example

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Sample()
    Dim stringA As String, stringB As String
    
    stringA = "sid"
    stringB = "SiD"
    
    MsgBox stringA = stringB
End Sub
```

You can read more about it in [Option Compare Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-compare-statement)

**Way 2**

Convert it to uppercase or lower case and then compare

```
If UCase(LookupRange.Cells(I, 1).Value) = UCase(LookupValue) Then

'~~> OR

If LCase(LookupRange.Cells(I, 1).Value) = LCase(LookupValue) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = LookupValue Then` to

```
If StrComp(LookupRange.Cells(i, 1), LookupValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: You need `vbTextCompare` Try `MsgBox StrComp("sid", "SiD", vbBinaryCompare) = 0` and then try `MsgBox StrComp("sid", "SiD", vbTextCompare) = 0`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Many thanks. For some reason I thought the question was to make it case sensitive :) Yes you are right. However, what lead me to this is the fact that his code should, by default, be non case sensative.

Comment: I could be wrong he wanted non case sensitive as per title. :D Upvoted

Comment: Actually I normally go with your suggestion `UCase` or `LCase` depending on my mood on the day `UP` or `LOW` :D